# How do I configure JUnit Ant task to only produce output on failures?

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am configuring JUnit in Ant so that unit tests will be run on each build. I would like the output of *failing* tests to be printed in the Ant console output whenever they are run. I don't need to see any output from succeeding tests.

Here is the relevant bit of my `build.xml` file:

```
<junit>
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${build}"/>
    </classpath>
    <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
    <batchtest>
        <fileset dir="${src}" includes="my/tree/junit/"/>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
```

This produces almost what I want, failing tests are detailed in the Ant output, except that succeeding tests also write the following output:

```
    [junit] Testsuite: my.tree.junit.ExampleTest
    [junit] Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
```

I believe I have tried all the combinations listed in the [JUnit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) documentation, including:

- `printsummary` attribute
- `showoutput` attribute
- `formatter` element with each kind of `type`

My use case is running `ant` from the command line. As I write more tests, I don't want the output from succeeding tests to be so large that output from failing tests scrolls off the screen. I just want `ant` to be quiet unless there's a failing test that needs my attention. How can I configure Ant/JUnit to do this?

I am using Ant version 1.6.4 and JUnit 4.6.

Comment: Just added custom JUnit custom test runner possibility.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One possibility would be to define your own xml formatter with the '`classname`' attribute (and extending `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLJUnitResultFormatter`, potentially doing nothing on [`endTest()` or `endTestsuite()` methods](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/XMLJUnitResultFormatter.html)).
That formatter would ignore info message and only display failure messages.

---

Note: [this settings](http://www.troymaxventures.com/2008/05/freeform-projects-netbeans-junit-test.html) mention the possibility of only displaying failed tests:

```
<junit showoutput="true"
       fork="true"
       failureproperty="tests.failed"
       errorproperty="tests.failed">
    <batchtest todir="${test.results.dir}">
        <fileset dir="test">
            <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
    <classpath path="${classes.dir}:${junit.jar}:${test.classes.dir}"/>
    <formatter usefile="false" type="brief"/>
    <!-- <formatter type="xml"/> If missing, only displays failed tests -->
</junit>
```

Did you test that ?

<sup>Note: the "`showoutput="true"` and `<formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>`" can be a bit problematic, as illustrated by this [recent (February 2012) ticket](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=208654))</sup>

---

Yet another approch would be to define your ant Juint Test runner, supporting ant [`JUnitResultFormatter`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/JUnitResultFormatter.java.htm) and displaying only stderr messages.

The [`EclipseTestRunner`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/test/EclipseTestRunner.java.htm) from eclipse is a good example.

Comment: Thanks, the example you showed is essentially the same as what I had posted in my question, so I think the difference might be something to do with running it in the Netbeans context. I'll try implementing a custom formatter but I had hoped to avoid having to do that.

Comment: I implemented a custom formatter and was able to accomplish my original goal.

Comment: @Greg: that's great. If the  custom formatter is not too big, could you post it here (or at least the part which only prints error messages)?

Comment: Note: as of 3/27/12 the "this settings" is a dead link

Comment: @stevebot ok, I have found another link illustrating and using the same JUnit config. I have edited the answer.