# Suppress Java Exception Stacktrace in cucumber Reports

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am using cucumber-jvm for my Selenium Webdriver scripts and the cucumber reports output format is set to html format

```
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources/features",
    format = {"pretty", "html:target/site/cucumber-pretty",
            "json:target/cucumber.json"}
)
```

When any test fails, the full stacktrace is displaying on the HTML report file as shown below.

[image]

I want to suppress this full stacktrace and replace it with my own message. I have tried this in the below way but didn't helped.

```
 try
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    }
    catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.getMessage();
    }
```

Is there anyway to get rid of this?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714327/how-to-suppress-cucumber-junit-assertion-stack-trace
?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress Cucumber/Junit assertion stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714327/how-to-suppress-cucumber-junit-assertion-stack-trace)

Answer (score 0):

In your cucumber options you have `... format = {"pretty", ...` Change format option to "plugin" like this:

```
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources/features",
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/site/cucumber-pretty",
            "json:target/cucumber.json"}
)
```