# How does jUnit Task get its information

Tags: ant, junit

I understand that if I want xml output from my jUnit tests I can use the Ant task "jUnit" to generate such output.
I want to extend the amount of information shown in this generated xml file.
I have additional information in my class file that I want to be available in the XML file as well.

My questions are:

- Where is the information in the xml file coming from?
- Is the information coming from the specific jUnit runner class that
  is used to run the tests?
- Does the jUnit task only format the received information or is it
  generating the information itself?
- Does the jUnit Ant task change the received information? (So it will
  only show specific information and filter out everything I want to
  add)

Answer (score 2):

The JUnit task's XML formatter is implemented in the class `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLJUnitResultFormatter`, a listener that receives events during the execution of the JUnit tests. For example, when a "test ended" event is received, the formatter appends an XML element in memory for the test. [Here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/XMLJUnitResultFormatter.java)'s a link to the source code.

Based on what I read from the code:

- The schema of the XML is defined in the Ant task's code. Specifically the above mentioned class. The schema is discussed in [Spec. for JUnit XML Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442556/spec-for-junit-xml-output). The content of the report, e.g. test name and class name are fetched from the JUnit test classes themselves. Here's a Javadoc for the method that retrieves the test name:

  > JUnit 3.7 introduces TestCase.getName() and subsequent versions of JUnit remove the old name() method. This method provides access to the name of a TestCase via reflection that is supposed to work with version before and after JUnit 3.7.
  >
  > since Ant 1.5.1 this method will invoke `"public String getName()"` on any implementation of Test if it exists.
  >
  > Since Ant 1.7 also checks for JUnit4TestCaseFacade explicitly. This is used by junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.
- The task does not only format the output. It generates all the report itself using the mentioned formatter. A couple of posts that may be helpful to extend the formatter:

  [How do I configure JUnit Ant task to only produce output on failures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963480/how-do-i-configure-junit-ant-task-to-only-produce-output-on-failures)

  [Custom JUnit Report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727616/custom-junit-report)

  A proposed solution is to write a custom formatter class extending `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLJUnitResultFormatter` and provide it in the `classname` attribute of the `formatter` element.